# How can I rig mesh (from particle) on armature?

Tags: mesh, armature, particles

I got some mesh by particle.

(particle > Render > Dupi Object > 'ctrl+shift+A')

And I make a Armature, and parent meshes on that.
But..

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to attach each vertex (in mesh) on each bones.
(so I used 'Set Parent to - with Automatic Weights')

But They moved like they were one object.

I want to treat them like normal polygon mesh, but they still have particle properties I think.
And I can't remove that properties.......
(because I don't know what is that)

Please help me.
How can I attach them on armature with Automatic Weights
like normal polygon mesh?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. 
They have multi user data. So they have set as like one object.

Unlink short Key = U 'make single user > object and data'